# How can you use $this reffering to the controller in a codeIgniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, this

I am using CodeIgniter, and in one of my models I would like to refer the `$this` which is used in `$this->load->model` and `$this->load->view`, instead of the `$this` which refers to the object itself.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Lemiant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `$this` to refer to anything but the model object itself, meaning you won't be able to do `$this = ...`.

But you can get the controller instance using the following function:

```
$controller = &get_instance();
```

As aularon reminded though, if your application is designed such that you *have* to access your controller from a model, then perhaps you might want to rethink its implementation.

Comment: but keep in mind that you usually shouldn't do things with a controller from a model, right?